# Number of elements in a static array

Tags: c

How to get an output that tells me that I have `56` elements in this array.

```
static uint16_t test[200] = 
{
    50, 32, 1, 5, 23, 5, 7, 56, 754, 6, 
    243, 23, 5, 5, 6, 35, 35, 67, 3, 5324, 
    51, 24, 23, 4, 2346, 54, 45, 345, 32, 4, 
    234, 12, 5, 43, 656, 37, 563, 6, 542, 543, 
    52, 35, 342, 673, 3, 6, 54, 624, 3, 545, 
    2, 345, 2435, 24, 6, 54
};
```

I have tried different things that work if it is not static and the number of max elements is not set. Like

```
int count = 0;
uint16_t *p;

for(p = test; p < &test + 1; p++)
    count++;
```

Or,

```
sizeof(test) / sizeof(uint16_t);
```

But as soon as it sets the maximum of elements to `200` then it always returns `200`.

Comment: `sizeof test / sizeof *test`. `sizeof(int)` does not make sense, it is not an array of `int`s, but of `uint16_t`

Comment: If I understood correctly, AFAIK your goal is unachievable.

Comment: Hint: The array size is determined at compile time, if not a VLA

Comment: Use another variable that tells you that there are only 56 valid items in the array. The other 144 will be nicely 0 in your case.

Comment: I guess you can change the `[200]` to just `[]`.

Comment: Why do you make the array larger than needed? Are you going to "add" more elements later?

Comment: @mch sizeof(test)/sizeof(uint16_t) ofcourse, writing mistake :d

Comment: C is a low-level language, where variables are actual memory locations. It's impossible to have "nothing" as the value of a variable as you might in other languages. So an array with 200 locations has, and will always have, 200 values in it. They may be specific values, or 0, or unspecified. But they have to be something. If you need to a type of array with a separate capacity and current size, you'll have to use variables for that and control them yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to get an output that tells me that I have 56 elements in this array.
>
> ```
> static uint16_t test[200] = 50,32,1,5,23,5,7,56,754,6,243,23,5,5,6,35,35,67,3,5324,51,24,23,4,2346,54,45,345,32,4,234,12,5,43,656,37,563,6,542,543,52,35,342,673,3,6,54,624,3,545,2,345,2435,24,6,54};
> ```

You won't, because your assumption is wrong. This array has 200 elements, no matter what. If you only initialize the first 56 of it, the others are *default-initialized* to `0` -- they are still there.

That said, if `0` isn't considered a "valid" value, you could simply count the "valid" ones like e.g.

```
size_t count;
for (count = 0; test[count]; ++count);
```

Otherwise, just hold the actual count of *used places* in a variable.

---

Side note, your calculation of the array size

```
sizeof(test)/sizeof(int)
```

is wrong, because the type doesn't match. To avoid errors like this, don't use type names with `sizeof` but always expressions:

```
sizeof test / sizeof *test
```

`*test` here evaluates to the first element, which has type `uint16_t`, and that's the type used by `sizeof`. Also note parantheses aren't needed when you use `sizeof` with an expression.

Comment: It could be useful to also mention using `static uint16_t test[] = { … };` to have the compiler count the elements and set the array size.

Comment: Okay perfect, a 0 would be a perfect indication of the end in the array !

Comment: @Noob14 if you want to use the 0 this way, remember to make the array one larger than the maximum "valid" items you want to have. Otherwise, your counting would run over the end of the array, never finding a 0, when it is "full"

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I make the counter do that, how is it allocating memory? I'm on a microcontroller and would like to have as much control of the memory as possible :-)

Comment: @Noob14 also consider using and maintaining a counting variable anyways, this might be more efficient than always searching from the start.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sure, I will make enough space, I know the MAX but there is no garantee that every single place in the array is going to be used :-)

Comment: @Noob14: When the declaration does not specify the array size in the brackets, the compiler counts the initializers and uses that count for the array size. The compiler allocates memory for the resulting array the same way it does as if the dimension had been explicitly stated (likely by reserving space in a data section in the object module).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to store elements in an array

```
1. Static
2. Dynamic
```

In static case we know the number of elements in the array, so you pre-define the value.
Like

```
uint16_t test[200]; -- Array to store 200 elements.
```

In dynamic case, we don't know the number of elements in the array so use dynamic memory allocation to store values and keep count of number of elements added.

Comment: Or you could let the initializer decide the size, in your "static" case. Or you have a reasonable maximum size (like the 200 here) and just hold the current count in a variable.

Comment: @FelixPalmen If there are dynamic updated and if we can't predefine the array size better to have dynamic memory allocation

Comment: which is guessing, OP doesn't describe his usecase.

Comment: "*know the number*" should read "*know the number* **at compile time**".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the length to 200 then the compiler will set it to the initialized values.

```
  u_int16_t test[] = {1,4,6};
  int len = sizeof (test) / sizeof (u_int16_t);   // n = 3
```

If you need to set the length of test AND you know your last element is not 0 (!), then you can count the 0s at the end and substract it from 200. Then you know the number of elements too.

Comment: But this way is not static? I want to know exactly(or as exactly as possible) how much memory I'm allocating before running the code :D

Comment: Then you set the size and init with an element that is not allowed before put your real values in. Then count the init-values at the end and you know the number of values.